# Reattaching an EBS volume to a new instance that was previously accidentally deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just want to preface this question by saying I've checked a few other similar questions but none really answered mine.

So the situation (hypothetically) is this: I have an EC2 instance running with one EBS volume as his root device. I forgot to turn on termination protection, oops, and I accidentally delete my server. Luckily, I set my EBS volume to persist after termination (**sidequestion, can you verify this setting without using the API?)**

Now, I have an AMI that is a week old. So I want to create a new EC2 instance, **but** I want to attach the orphaned EBS volume to it, since that has the newest data, settings and whatnot. **How can I achieve this?**

Am I missing some information here? Is the EC2 instance just a shell, where the EBS volume is essentially my server? Should I just take a snapshot from my EBS volume, create an AMI from that and then launch a new instance that will be the same as the orphaned one?

And while I'm here asking questions, one for the road; **You can either create a volume or an image from a snapshot, why would you prefer one over the other?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an indirect answer to one of my many questions.

You can reattach a root device volume. On a Linux instance that has no EBS volumes attached, when attaching the EBS volume, name it **/dev/xvda** and it will register as the root device.